# My pipeline ins't inserting the whole data I just scraped

Tags: mysql, scrapy, pipeline, web-crawler

Well I'm almost done with this project but I can't figure out why my pipeline just inserts a few of the items that my spider just scraped. Here is my code:

First the item:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PruebaMercadoLibreItem(Item):
    producto = Field()
    precio = Field()
```

Now my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from prueba_mercadolibre.items import PruebaMercadoLibreItem


class MLSpider(Spider):
    name = "mlspider"
    allowed_domains = ["mercadolibre.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mercadolibre.com.mx"]

    def parse (self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'item-data')]")
        for title in titles:
            item = PruebaMercadoLibreItem()
            item["producto"] = title.xpath("p[@class='title']/@title").extract()[0]
            item["precio"] = title.xpath("span[@class='ch-price']/text()").extract()[0]
            yield item
```

And finaly my pipeline:

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

class PruebaMercadoLibrePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, dbpool):
        self.dbpool = dbpool

    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        dbargs = dict(
            host=settings['MYSQL_HOST'],
            db=settings['MYSQL_DBNAME'],
            user=settings['MYSQL_USER'],
            passwd=settings['MYSQL_PASSWD'],
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True,
    )
        dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', **dbargs)
        return cls(dbpool)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        d = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._do_upsert, item, spider)
        d.addErrback(self._handle_error, item, spider)
        d.addBoth(lambda _: item)

        return d

    def _do_upsert(self, conn, item, spider):
        conn.execute("""
            INSERT INTO productos (producto, precio)
            VALUES (%s, %s)
        """, (item['producto'], item['precio']))



    def _handle_error(self, failure, item, spider):
        log.err(failure)
```

Ok and my settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'prueba_mercadolibre'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['prueba_mercadolibre.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'prueba_mercadolibre.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'prueba_mercadolibre.items.PruebaMercadoLibreItem'


ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'prueba_mercadolibre.pipelines.PruebaMercadoLibrePipeline',
]

MYSQL_HOST = 'localhost'
MYSQL_DBNAME = 'ejercicio_2'
MYSQL_USER = 'root'
MYSQL_PASSWD = 'root'
```

Ok and finally my db is simple but ill just leave its code here:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ejercicio_2` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE         utf8_general_ci ;
USE `ejercicio_2` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ejercicio_2`.`productos` (
  `id` INT ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `producto` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `precio` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Few thoughts: try increasing columns sizes, probably 45 is not enough. Also, try calling `conn.commit()` after the `execute()` call.

Comment: Also, try printing out items to the log in `process_item()` and `_do_upsert()` and see if all of the items being processed are there.

Comment: lol,i feel so stupid, the lenght of the data wasnt enough, lol thx for your help again @alecxe